# syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

i can't run my Rspec user_spec.rb test due to a syntax error. i already try to add and deletes some "end" but it seem the problem still not resolve.

---

[this is my static_pages_spec.rb](http://pastebin.com/YxbHXzLn#)

---

this is my first question so maybe it a little weird.

Comment: Please include the source. And, indentation usually solves such trivial problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your do/ends appear to match to me. Does the syntax error specify a line number? I noticed two potential issues on line 25 and 48 from your pastebin link.

```
expect(page) .to have_content( 'Help' )
```

should be

```
expect(page).to have_content( 'Help' )
```

Also

```
expect(page) .to have_content( 'About Us' )
```

should be

```
expect(page).to have_content( 'About Us' )
```

Comment: i already doing that and it still doesn't fix the problem.                   here is my error screenshot .http://imgur.com/RD54nfM

Comment: Can you post your app/helpers/application_helper.rb file?

Comment: It looks like you need one more 'end' at the bottom of your application_helper. Right now, there is one for 'def' and one for 'if', but you also need one for 'module'.

Answer (score -1):

Try with only a single `require` statement and a single `describe` block.